# ArrayList de Objetos

Tags: java, poo

Como puedo crear ArrayList de Objetos en Java
tengo una clase abstracta Persona que es mi Super clase y tengo clases hijas profesor, estudiante quiero crear una lista dinámica .

Comment: Hola Joan. ¿Has investigado algo? ¿Qué has intentado en base a lo investigado? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes en lo que has intentado? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Si solo dices tengo este deber resuelvan no es bien recibido.

Comment: Hola. Sería más fácil ayudarte si incluyeras más información de tu problema y el código que tienes, pues de otra forma es muy dificil adivinar que es lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo con java *a pie*:

```
List<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<>();
```

Y ahí puedes agregar instancias de Profesor y Estudiantes (u otra subclase de Persona).

Comment: ¿Como instanciaria a Profesor?

Comment: @Joan Ej: `personas.add(new Profesor(...));`

Answer (score 0):

¿De que tipo necesitas tu ArrayList?

De ser de alguna de las clases hijas declaras primero el ArrayList Abstracto

`List<Persona> personas;`

Y luego debes de inicializarla como una clase hija:

`personas = new ArrayList<Estudiante>();`

Como te comentaron, intenta especificar más tu pregunta y publica lo que has intentado, te ayudará mucho. Saludos!